# Automatically trigger builds ONLY for PR branches in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to do the following:

- A developer (e.g.: James) could be working on this private branch (e.g.: `james/add-custom-logger`) for a while before sending out a PR.
- Once James sends out a PR, I would like to automatically trigger a build for that PR branch.

I am struggling to figure out how to do this in VSTS builds.
I know that I could setup build triggers based on branches like `feature/*` and could ask all developers to follow that pattern, so in this case it would be `feature/james/add-custom-logger`.

But I don't want to trigger those branches **until** a pull request is sent for those branches.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe branch policies fit your scenario. If james always creates the PR to the same branch - for example 'master' - you can create a branch policy for 'master'. Go to `Repos > Branches > ... (More Actions) > Branch policies > Build validation > Add build policy`

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/repos/git/branch-policies?view=vsts#build-validation
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/build/ci-build-git?view=vsts&tabs=yaml#validate-pull-requests

Comment: Thanks @renklus. Yeah my colleague mentioned to me about this yesterday.